# Django unable to connect to MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django version (1.10) which is installed on my MacBookPro (El Capitan OS X) and I would like to connect the API to my MySQL Database which is located on a distant server (Ubuntu - same network as my job network).

I get this error when I'm running the Django server :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.30.10.58' (61)")
```

This is my `settings.py` file from my project :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Etat_Civil',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '172.30.10.58',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

On my Mac I installed `mysqlclient` / `mysql connector/python`

I don't work with a virtual environment because I just have one project in my laptop. So it's not necessary to isolate Python.

I think that's maybe a permission problem but I don't really know How configure that. I found some tutorials but I get problems each time.

Do you have some ideas ?

Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Looks like the remote machine isn't accepting connections from your laptop. Ask for assistance from whoever manages the database server.

Comment: Even if you have only one project, it is always a good thing to use virtual env. For the issue, make sure that your mysql database accepts remote connections.

Comment: It's hardly surprising that your office doesn't allow incoming connections on the mysql port from an external IP

Comment: I just have to allow permissions for all users. But I don't know the process to do that. I have access on this virtual server because I created it and I added the MySQL Database.
I don't know exactly How I can give all access to my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to allow remote connections by editing `my.cnf` file and commenting the line that starts with `bind-address` as follows (You may also just change `127.0.0.1`by your machine ip address):

```
#bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Grant privileges to your user as follows:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'172.30.10.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.30.10.%'
```

To grant privileges only on `Etat_Civil`, you can try:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Etat_Civil.* TO 'root'@'172.30.10.%'
```

Comment: Is it normal when I execute privileges command from MySQL : `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)` ?

Comment: I do not remember the command output but you can check the connection from your app after you run those commands

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MySQL is configured to listen only on localhost.

You can test this by running telnet 172.30.10.59 3306 from your client machine.

Please try to follow Configuration step described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html):

Edit the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to configure MySQL to listen for connections from network hosts, change the bind-address directive to the server's IP address. For example Replace 172.30.10.59 with the appropriate address. If there are no such entry - uncomment it or create new line.

```
 bind-address = 172.30.10.59
```

Then restart mysqld with this command:

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

Then test with telnet or by running your application once again. Also netstat would have second entry for mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be 'HOST': '172.30.10.58'
You can change IP address to your hostname.

1. If you are using Ubuntu, check the name in
   sudo vi /etc/hostname and sudo vi /etc/hosts
2. If you are using docker, go to docker

   docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash

   sudo vi /etc/hostname and sudo vi /etc/hosts

Hope this help !